# how to directly specify second parameter while opening a cursor when first parameter has a default value set

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper

I came across this situation where I provide a default value for the first parameter of the cursor and simply declare the second parameter as shown in the code snippet.
I want to skip inputting the first parameter value while opening the cursor and pass only the value for second parameter.
Is there any way to do this ? 
I get error if I simply put a comma and second parameter value or just the second parameter value.

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    DECLARE 
        VEID TMP_EMPLOYEES.NAME%TYPE;
        CURSOR CURF(VID VARCHAR2:=5,vname varchar2) IS--default value set
        SELECT NAME FROM TMP_EMPLOYEES
        WHERE ID<VID and name like'%'||vname||'%';
    BEGIN 
        OPEN CURF('4','ra');-- I just want to pass 'ra'
        LOOP
        FETCH CURF INTO VEID;

        EXIT WHEN CURF%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VEID);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE CURF;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE');
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using named notation you can clarify which arguments you are passing to the cursor/procedure/function you are calling.

The following calls would generate the same result:

```
CURF('4', 'ra')
CURF(vid => '4', vname => 'ra')
CURF(vname => 'ra', vid => '4') -- Order of named arguments don't matter
CURF('4', vname => 'ra') -- Mixing ordered and named arguments
```

By using named notation you can omit arguments with default values i.e. `CURF(vname => 'ra')` will give the wanted result

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Now I feel like I asked a silly question‍♂️